# Google Cloud Messaging suitability for pub/sub Location system

Tags: android, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-messaging, faye

I'm looking to create a system which monitors the location of a fleet of drivers, and allows for the bi-directional communication between a driver and a dispatcher. Upstream messages from driver to dispatcher will include current location data of the driver. Downstream messages will include location data of the entire fleet so that a live map of the fleet can be maintained at the drivers end. A pub/sub architecture is suited to this, with each driver a client of a server which broadcasts location data. I've looked into a number of possibilities, including Faye and rabbitmq. Google cloud messaging CCS looks like it has some really nice features, in particular asynchronous messaging, and I'm leaning towards using that. However, it is usually used for sending notifications to users to download an update. I'm put off by it because it is advertised with a different purpose in mind.

(i) Can it be easily manipulated to do what I want? 
(ii) How suitable is it for what I'm looking for?
(iii) If not are Faye/RabbitMq better options?

Comment: If you need a hosted cloud based solution, [CloudAMQ](http://www.cloudamqp.com/) (RabbitMQ as a Service) might be worth a look.

Comment: This link shows a test performed with RabbitMQ in GCE http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.nl/2014/06/rabbitmq-on-google-compute-engine.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you may be looking for [Google Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/).